# How to send mail in background use android

Tags: android, email, background

I need make an application send email automatic when user click a button
I use Java mail but it not working now because policy security of google.

I can use other mail server but I not found other solution.
Please help me.

Comment: you have using SendGrid method ??

Comment: Hi, i dont know sendgrid method

Comment: Hi @HardikParmar, I made an account for SendGrid but I can't create API key.